# CucumberJvmSMFormatter Error on IntelliJ IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, automation, cucumber

Why am I getting below error while running feature file in IntellijIDE with Java/Selenium + cucumber framework?

```
Error running 'Scenario: validating utag data on Login page ': org/jetbrains/plugins/cucumber/java/run/CucumberJvmSMFormatter
```

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185778

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue but was fixed after doing the following: Uninstall the gherkin plugin and the cucumber for java plugin and then reinstall them.

File -> Settings -> Plugin