# CucumberJvmSMFormatter: start has failed

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, cucumber-jvm

Here is total information about my project:
- Cucumber for Java v191.6014.8;
- Gherkin v191.5849.16;
- II 2019 Community.
After start I get message: "Error running... /CucumberJvmSMFormatter". 
But that decision didn't help me.

[CucumberJvmSMFormatter Error on IntelliJ IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51108935/cucumberjvmsmformatter-error-on-intellij-ide)

I expect the normal start of my test, but I see the message "Error running... /CucumberJvmSMFormatter"

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a mismatch between Cucumber version and IntelliJ / plugin version.

Try installing the Cucumber plugin again. If that doesn't work, try removing the `CucumberJvmSMFormatter` from your run arguments.